# How make padding changing more smooth and optimised

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, event-handling

I am making same modal as in telegram.
If to much elements in modal it became scrollable and when you scroll close to bottom enough padding bottom (in term of outside element ) or  margin bottom (in term of scrolling element) became bigger.

**initial**
[image]

**scrolling padding increase**

[image]

the code I implement this:

```
import { cn } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { debounce } from "lodash";

const CreateChatModal = () => {
  const [padding, setPadding] = useState(0);
  const scrollableDiv = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const current = scrollableDiv.current;

    const handleScroll = debounce(() => {
      if (current) {
        const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = current;
        const spaceLeft = Math.max(scrollHeight - scrollTop - clientHeight, 0);
        console.log(spaceLeft);

        if (spaceLeft > 30) {
          setPadding(0);
        }

        if (spaceLeft < 30) {
          setPadding(31 - spaceLeft);
        }
      }
    }, 8);

    if (current) {
      current.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }

    return () => {
      if (current) {
        current.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className="absolute w-full h-full  bg-black/40 pt-[60px]"
      style={{ paddingBottom: `${padding}px` }}
    >
      <div
        className={cn(
          "w-[438px] mx-auto rounded-t-lg bg-white flex flex-col max-h-full",
          padding > 0 ? "rounded-b-lg" : "rounded-b-none"
        )}
      >
        <div className="h-[60px] ">Header</div>
        <div ref={scrollableDiv} className="overflow-y-scroll h-full ">
          <div className="h-[100px]">Item</div>
          <div className="h-[100px]">Item</div>
          <div className="h-[100px]">Item</div>
          <div className="h-[100px]">Item</div>
          <div className="h-[100px]">last Item</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateChatModal;
```

the problem is animation when padding changes not always smooth, in times when I scroll fast especially (